Issue while iterating related child records of a Case Object in Visualforce Email Template for Portal users
Requirement - To show the table consists of the child records in Visualforce Email Template for portal users
Design -
We have two Objects having Master-Detail Relationship.
First Object - Parent__c (Case)
Second Object - Child__c
Whenever, customer submits the parent record in the community portal, we are creating the child records for the respective parent and sending the child records information in the Visualforce Email Template.
We have created a Visualforce Email Template as mentioned below -

The issue here is whenever we are trying with any internal user then., the mail is coming properly with the table as soon as the portal user having community license submits the parent record in portal then, the table is coming as blank.
We have already checked the below things-
FLS,
Object CRUDS,
Sharing Settings
Please help us out. why the table is not populating the child records only for the community portal user?
